# How to make link_to dependent from the userrole in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I want to create a new user role which is very limited. How can I prevent that this uses a link?

I can hide links with this but not deactivte.

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', product, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

If a user knows about the link they can use this, and that can not happen

How can I make this?

Comment: Redirect in the destroy controller method if the user isn't an admin.

Comment: You may wish to set up authorization within your application. The [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is a popular way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is an authorization gem.
Take a look at the following: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization

Cancan is the standard, but a lot of people prefer Pundit.